# Make character in front mandatory / required

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match the following pattern: N.N.N

324324.234324.234324 matches, as well as 1.1.1

[I have the following pattern:](https://regexr.com/45aqq)

```
(\d*\.\d*\.\d*)
```

Problem is, it matches N.N. already at the second dot, so, how can I make the following number *mandatory*?

Comment: Turn the last * into a +?

Comment: `*` is 0 or more, `+` is 1 or more. I agree with Chris, but you probably want that for all digits, not just the last one. (otherwise `..5` would also match.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` and `$` anchors and also change `*` to `+` since at least one number is required

also, `(\d*\.){2}` can be used to simplify `\d+\.\d+\.`

```js
[
   '324324.234324.234324',
   '324324.234324.'
].forEach(test =>
  console.log(/^(\d+\.){2}\d+$/.test(test))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to one or more non greedy `+?`

`(\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+)`

Comment: Non-greedy doesn't really matter because the dot is not a digit.

Comment: Thats a fair comment @Ivar also I had to edit and remove last non greedy